# CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON works intermittently

Tags: gmail-addons

I have CardService.newOpenLink() in my add-on that does authentication from our web site. Upon return I am using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile() to pass self-closing file that is closing pop-up with authentication code. Everything works.
The issue I an having - I am using setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON) with my open link, so I can reload add-on and re-read cached credentials. This works intermittently - sometimes add-on is reloaded and sometimes it stays on a current card. I cannot catch the pattern...  Any suggestions on what could be the issue?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is some kind of timing issue. The way my flow works - I open external HTML window, which is reloading itself with URL pointing back to my script. Script is using HtmlService to pass back simple page that will close itself. If I put window.close() inside setTimeout() - then Add-On will reload reliably if timeout is 5 sec. or more. Anything less than 2 sec will not reload at all. 2 to 5 sec will work intermittently.  Not sure what Google is doing there, but apparently they are loosing handle to a window...

Comment: Still having this issue?